# Disable add-on update dialoge box in Firefox

Tags: firefox, browser-addons

How can I disable the add-on update dialogue box that appears after an extension is updated in Firefox?

I’ve searched the web, and I’ve looked for an `about:config` setting, but could not find any that seemed to be related.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting *app.update.silent* to true in the about:config.
I'm not sure if that silence might have some other implications as well, as far as not letting you know when updates occur.

Comment: actually this seems to not have worked, as the update notification box reappeared on a recent update. i checked and the config setting is still set to true...